# Why does the fan stop in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fan

I have Windows 7 installed on [ProBook 4530S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_ProBook#S-Series). How can I configure it so that the fan remains always on running?

When the fan stops, the system halts and the screen freezes. I have a dual-boot system on another OS (Unix-based) with the fan always on and don't have a problem.

Answer (score 4):

There will be BIOS settings for this (based on temp) or change under your Advanced (Active) Power Profile the CPU loads/use %'s to all read 100% and you should (might!) find the CPU fan doesn't then throttle/stop.

Comment: There is only one setting "Fan Always on When on Power". Shld I update bios?

Comment: What is that setting set to? Updating the BIOS is unlikely to give you additional power settings.

Comment: its checked i.e. true

Comment: Any other settings you can see about throttling the CPU?